Split AC - outdoor fan hissing sound and the white colour connections torn
It is a brand new split AC. Aged only 6 months.
I just randomly heard hissing sound coming from the outdoor fan and also the white connections seem to be torn a little.
Just noticed how they could get torn.
Any idea? Should I check with a technician, or is it normal?

I've heard hissing noises occasionally on the outside of a window AC, which is essentially the same thing as the outside of a mini-split. I can't be sure, but I think the compressor sometimes makes such noises. That said, a picture of this white connection might help.

You will get guesses without a pic.
